# Can anybody explain me how does this code creates a class that implements an interface and also instantiates the class?

Tags: java, spring

The interface

```
public interface MessageService {
    String getMessage();
}
```

The Class(I have doubt in)

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class Application {
    //---------
    @Bean
    MessageService mockMessageService(){
        return new MessageService(){
            public String getMessage(){
                return "Hello World! Yash";
            }
        };
    }
    //---------
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Application.class);
        MessagePrinter printer = context.getBean(MessagePrinter.class);
        System.out.println(printer.service.getClass().getName());
        printer.printMessage();
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain me how the code marked between ------ works without giving any implements keyword in class definition and it also creates an object of that class in that line itself?

You can refer to this link of Spring quickstart guide

https://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/#quick-start

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Spring, but with Java itself.

You are using anonymous class, which lets you declare and instantiate a class at the same time. Here you are declaring an anonymous class which implements `MessageService` and override its `getMessage()` method, and instantiate the anonymous class at the same time.

Remember anonymous class has similar scopes and restrictions with a local class. The main difference is anonymous classes cannot be given a class name, thus you cannot define their constructors. Note also anonymous classes can either implement a single interface (in which case the syntax is `new InterfaceName() {...}`, or extend a single concrete or abstract class (in which case the syntax is `new ClassName([argument list]){...}`).

Answer (score 0):

From [JLS Sec 15.9.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.1):

> If the class instance creation expression ends in a class body, then the class being instantiated is an anonymous class. Then:
>
> ...
>
> Let T be the type denoted by ClassOrInterfaceTypeToInstantiate. If Tdenotes a class, then an anonymous direct subclass of T is declared. If Tdenotes an interface, **then an anonymous direct subclass of Object that implements T is declared**.